# Implementing smooth transitions in a Java progress bar

Tags: java, opengl

I have successfully programmed my own progress bar, where the bar visually updates based on the changing percentage value. However, I'm currently facing an issue with the abrupt jumps between different stages of the progress bar. I would like to achieve a smooth transition between these stages.

Here are some additional details: I have access to the FPS count of the game, as well as the position and scale of the progress bar. My programming language of choice is Java.

**My question is:** How can I implement a smooth transition between stages in my progress bar given the available information?

Any suggestions or guidance on achieving this smooth transition would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code. Instead of directly setting the width, you could increase each frame the width until it's the desired width/percentage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general answer, not language specific.

Instead of directly setting the width, you could increase each frame the width until its the desired width/percentage.

Let's assume you have the function `bar.setWidth(val)` to set the width of your progress bar.

Let this be your update loop (ran at `60FPS`):

```
update {
   ...
   ...

   double percentageLoaded; // this is your parameter probably

   static const int incrementStep = 1; // increase this for faster animation

   // Get the width of the bar for the current percentage   
   int desiredWidth = percentageLoaded * bar.totalWidth;


   if(bar.currentWidth < desiredWidth) {
      bar.currentWidth += incrementStep;
   }
}
```

There are still a few things you have to check if your incrementStep is larger than 1. (eg: don't set the bar width larger than 100%)

Here is a small drawing, maybe it helps you understand better. In this example the increment step is `1px`, the bar width is `4px` and the loading was set to be `50%` complete, this means that your bar should be `2px` in width.
[image]

Comment: undeerstood it and successfully implemented it, thanks! :)

Comment: I have one more question...
If I have a small value (lets say 0.001) for the increment step to be sure, that the transition is completely smooth there is an issue, if the loading is e.g. ready in 2 seconds, because the bar needs at least 20 seconds or so...

Is there any solution to this problem? Maybe that the step grows exponentially with the distance? Can you help me please...
Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, you could calculate incrementStep based on the distance between current bar width and desired bar width. Eg: if you want the animation to take one second and the difference to animate is 40px and your fps is 60fps then the increment step is 40px/(60fps * 1 second)

Comment: With FPS, make sure you clamp it at some value.